# libgdx inputeventlistener events

Tags: java, libgdx

I added an inputlistener in a stage and in actor A. I only want to fire the event in the stage's listener if the actor being touched is **not** actor A.

Is there any implemented function that I can use in the listener of the stage to check if an actor is touched? Or prevent the stage's event from firing inside actor A's event.

i.e inside stage's touch down:

```
if(*actor touched is not A*)
   //do some stuff
```

or in actor A's touch down, don't fire the stage's event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the `InputListener` events provide an `InputEvent` which in turn provides the `Actor` on which the event was performed via `getTarget()`. For example, if you are handling the `touchUp` event:

```
public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button)
{
  if (!A.equals(event.getTarget()))
  {
    // Handle the event
  }
}
```